# Samsung Contacts App Connection to My App

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, samsung-mobile

My App creates contacts in Android using the ContactsContract and a custom Mimetype.  On HTC and in the Emulator, the contact is displayed in an Actions section that I can tap on and it take me to my application's activity.  When the same application is run on a Samsung Galaxy device the contact is rendered in the "Connected via" section, but the icon isn't clickable.  I'm sure its possible to make this work because WhatsApp application renders in the same place and it is clickable.  I have browsed the Contacts Content URIs and can't see any significant different about the contacts that WhatsApp makes and my contacts.

I think the contacts.xml and manifest portions are relevant and included below.

contacts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ContactsDataKind
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.bmarko.contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:detailSocialSummary="true" />

</ContactsSource>
```

snippet of manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.bmarko.dialer.views.newconversation.NewConversationActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.bmarko.contact" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I have the same problem at the moment...

Comment: No, this is still an open issue in my bug tracker.  Its not a huge problem for me as users have alternate ways to get to contacts in my app.  But its very annoying.

Comment: Have you tried combining the <intent-filter> tags?

Comment: I have tried with a single intent filter with action of SEND and separately VIEW.   I did specify both actions and the */* mime type for the testing.  I didn't see any change in behavior.